# How to display the errors in a meteor view template

Tags: meteor

How can I go about getting the value of the errors I have thrown in a fails insert on a collection or in a method.

```
Customers.allow({
insert: function(userID, rec) {
    console.log(userID === rec.userID);

    if (rec.userID === null) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(600, "You must be logged in");
    };

    if (rec.phone.length != 10 ) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(601, "Incorect phone format", "Phone must be 10 chars long");
    };

    if (rec.fax.length != 10 ) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(602, "Incorect fax format", "Fax must be 10 chars long");
    };

    return userID === rec.userID;
}
```

});

So right now i see the error on the console but say if wanted this display the errors in the template or store it in a reactive session so it can be shown to the user to correct.

like try to to something like this.

```
Template.form.errors = function () {
   // return however you get to those thrown errors
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to make this work? Solution provided by Tarang does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: ok works for me now I added a comment in Tarang's answer that made it work for me

Answer (score 2):

There was a package just released today to help with this : https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-errors

You would need meteorite to use it : https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite

Add the package with meteorite:

```
mrt add errors
```

(Don't worry you're not adding errors to your meteor besides the command ;)

You can then throw errors in your client js:

```
Meteor.Errors.throw("Error details");
```

Then wherever you want to display errors use, in your HTML:

```
{{>meteorErrors}}
```

Comment: For me Meteors.Errors.throw("Error details") didn't work but Errors.throw("Error details") did. When you want to bring the errors back to the client the following worked:   Meteor.call('yourMethod', yourOptions, function(err){ if (err) Errors.throw(err.reason); });